# Feature importance by output for a predictive model

Tags: python, xgboost

I wanted to predict employee turnover for my company, so I used a dataset set with different factors (SALARY, SATISFACTION, DISTANCE FROM HOME, ETC...) and was able to get a prediction whether the employee will leave or not. I also made a feature importance plot for the whole model.

[enter image description here]

[image: 1]

Here is what my results look like. Now I am trying to add feature importance by output. Basically, I wanna be able to see what top 3 factors impacted this employee to quit or will impact them to quit. So for each line with employee ID, I wanna be able to see the coefficients of the factors from highest to lowest. Can someone help with that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are describing is probably answered by doing a Shapley Additive Explanations analysis.

I would recommend you to use the `SHAP` python library. I will leave the link for its documentation, but I'm sure some of its functions will do the trick.

[SHAP Documentation](https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)